# PowerBuilder 12.5 : RichText Error

Tags: powerbuilder

I am facing the follow error while using Jaguar. I also deployed PBRTC120.DLL.

Is there another dll which I need to deploy or am I supposed to change my enviromental variable. **

```
     ---------------------------   
      RichText Error   
     ---------------------------  
      Load rich text edit module error
     ---------------------------   
      OK      
     ---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the powerbuilder runtime packer to build a package with richtext support, so that will automatically include all the necessary DLLs. Later you can install the package and see what dlls are included for richtext support.